# Execute stored procedure and using returned information in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My previous question on this subject was poorly asked, so I want to start by asking a more concise question that is really the core of my issue.  In my .cs Model, I have to call a stored procedure that brings up the number of tasks for each  project.

The specific thing I need is the number of tasks that each project may have, which is returned as the sp parameter UnfinishedTaskCount.

The razor in my cshtml file will display the returned information, which was another issue I managed to figure out, but getting the info I want is the final hurdle.  Here is the code in the .cs file where I need to have the correct call to the stored procedure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace IntelliBase.Models
{
    public partial class Project:Description
    {
       ....

        private int unfinishedtasks;
        public int UnFinishedTaskCount
        {
            get
            {
                SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ORLANDOSQL1;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                Object returnValue;

                cmd.CommandText = "mp_Display_Projects_Home";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BeginPage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndPage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

                sqlConnection1.Open();
                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                sqlConnection1.Close();

                return unfinishedtasks = (int)returnValue;
            }
            set { ; }
        }

    }
}
```

The ExecuteScalar command will only bring back the first row information, which doesn't help since there are more rows of projects each with their own set of tasks, and I read that ExecuteNonQuery will not return specific parameters, just all the data; I don't need all the data, just the UnfinishedTaskCount for each project.

So because of the ExecuteScalar, it returns "2" for the number of tasks for all the projects in the table because the project in the first row has two tasks (the other projects have different numbers of tasks).  Is there another Execute-- call that will grab the correct number of tasks for each project so I can display them correctly on the cshtml?  I appreciate everyone's patience; this is my first big C# project and I'm kind of anxious to get this working correctly.

Comment: You need to include the basic structure (column names data type) i n order to get an valid answer. There are also numerous problems with your code.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

1. Your model should not be touching the database. That's the job of the controller.
2. You need to read the entire resultset from the stored procedure, and use it to fill your model. If there's one row per product, then there would be one model object per row. Use `ExecuteReader`, not `ExecuteScalar`.
3. You have several objects in your code which implement `IDisposable`, so they should be in `using` blocks:

   ```
   using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(
                           "Data Source=ORLANDOSQL1;Integrated Security=True"))
   {
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
       {
           using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (reader.Read()
               {
                   // Create an instance of your model object,
                   // fill it from the reader, then add it to the collection
                   // of model objects
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

Pretend your model object is called "Product" and has two properties, "ID" and "NumberOfUnfinishedTasks". Pretend your SP returned a set of {ID, NumberOfUnfinishedTasks}. Then

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
while (reader.Read()
{
    // Create an instance of your model object,
    Product product = new Product();

    // fill it from the reader
    product.ID = (int) reader["ID"];
    product.NumberOfUnfinishedTasks = (int) reader["NumberOfUnfinishedTasks"];

    // then add it to the collection
    // of model objects
    products.Add(product);
}
```

Later:

```
return View(products);
```

Comment: So, I put the above into the controller?  I'm still not really following how to connect the data called in the controller into the collection of model objects.

Comment: The controller will call a method that reads from the database and _creates_ the collection of model objects. That collection of objects is what will be  used as the Model for the view.

Comment: I think I'm just a lost cause, because that didn't make anything any clearer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  You should change your answer as this part is not relevant "I really don't have time to spell it all out"